# com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties

Tags: rx-java2

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/rxjava.properties
>       File1: D:\Android\Android Studio\gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex.rxjava2\rxjava\2.0.2\cfccdd18cdfbe7b4773d42c9f3512eeafbe5cbf9\rxjava-2.0.2.jar
>       File2: D:\Android\Android Studio\gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex\rxjava\1.2.1\4e4cfa4adc74521d5966799fa5ab70b733552f68\rxjava-1.2.1.jar

Answer (score 5):

add this in app/build.gradle:

```
android {

```
......

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
```

}
```